# Infragistics Excel Cell Format to Time

Tags: c#, excel, infragistics

I am doing a export to excel using Infragistics excel . And I want to set the column type of the excel to 'Time'.  I'm formatting from db as a string but can change it to any dataType.

I've tried these but they come out as General or Custom format

```
// Formats as 'General' in Excel
String time = dataRow.ItemArray[columnIndex].ToString();
row.Cells[columnIndex].Value = time;

// Formats as 'Custom' in Excel
row.Cells[columnIndex].CellFormat.FormatString = "hh:mm:ss";
row.Cells[columnIndex].Value = dataRow.ItemArray[columnIndex].ToString();
```

Comment: What `FormatString` do you get if you create a spreadsheet in Excel, set the format of a cell to "Time" and read into your program? If that's the same then there'll be another property of `CellFormat` that you'll need to set as well.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm new to Infragistics and dont know how to import to read to cellFormat.

Comment: Please add to your question tags the details about what kind of technology you are using (WPF). This is a rather important thing to do to attract the experts on the matter.

Comment: Its a console app using InfragisticsWPF4.Documents.Excel.v13.1.dll to do the export of db value to an .xls

Comment: I'm not using WPF4 just the export function.

Comment: I went into Excel and run a macro and look at VBA code to find "hh:mm:ss;@".  Similar to what ChrisF said but didn't read into my program.